# Prove that if $A^2 = 0$ then $I - A$ is non singular and $(I-A)^{-1} = I + A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^2 = 0$, then $I − A$ is nonsingular and $(I − A)^{−1} = I + A$.

(Matrix Algebra)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  Remember your "$" signs!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Verify that $(I-A)(I+A)=I$.

Comment: can you further explain this please

Comment: Matrix multiplication distributes over addition and subtraction.  So distribute what is on the right.  Follow the given rule.  Show that it equals what is on the right.  If $(I-A)$ has an inverse, it must be non-singular.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, just as with numbers

$(1 + x)(1 -x) = (1 - x) + x(1 - x) = 1 - x + x - x^2 = 1 - x^2, \tag 1$

so with matrices

$(I - A)(I + A) = I - A^2; \tag 2$

the algebraic maneuvers are essentially the same in each case.  Now with

$A^2 = 0, \tag 3$

(2) becomes

$(I - A)(I + A) = I, \tag 4$

which shows both that $I - A$ is nonsingular and that

$(I - A)^{-1} = I + A; \tag 5$

we can also see that $I - A$ is nonsingular by taking determinants in (4):

$\det(I - A) \det(I + A) = \det (I) = 1, \tag 6$

which shows that

$\det(I - A) \ne 0 \ne \det(I + A). \tag 7$

Answer (score 0):

Nonsingularity follows from existence of an inverse. Note that
$$(I-A)(I+A) = I^2-AI+IA-A^2$$
Now do some (basic) matrix algebra, using the fact that $A^2=0$.

Comment: Actually we should prove also that $(I+A)(I-A)=I$. Even if for the $n\times n$ matrices suffices one of the two equalities, expecially in this case in wich we see only commuting matrices. Although given the elementary level of the assertion I think we shouldn't assume these shorthands.